# Помогите исправить ошибку при установки библиотеки pyinstaller

Tags: python

```
C:\Users\maksi>pip install pyinstaller
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached pyinstaller-5.6.2-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (1.2 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in c:\users\maksi\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files\python310\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (63.2.0)
Collecting pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2021.4
  Using cached pyinstaller_hooks_contrib-2022.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl (250 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0 in c:\users\maksi\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2022.5.30 in c:\users\maksi\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2022.5.30)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\maksi\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from pefile>=2022.5.30->pyinstaller) (0.18.2)
Installing collected packages: pyinstaller-hooks-contrib, pyinstaller
  WARNING: The scripts pyi-archive_viewer.exe, pyi-bindepend.exe, pyi-grab_version.exe, pyi-makespec.exe, pyi-set_version.exe and pyinstaller.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\maksi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pyinstaller-5.6.2 pyinstaller-hooks-contrib-2022.13


C:\Users\maksi>pyinstaller
"pyinstaller" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Comment: Здесь нет никакой ошибки при установке - "Successfully installed pyinstaller-5.6.2"

Comment: Возможно проблема в том, что директория `C:\Users\maksi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts` не добавлена в переменную среды. Из-за этого не получается вызвать `pyinstaller`.

Comment: Это видно из логов: `WARNING: The scripts pyi-archive_viewer.exe, pyi-bindepend.exe, pyi-grab_version.exe, pyi-makespec.exe, pyi-set_version.exe and pyinstaller.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\maksi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts' which is not on PATH.`

Comment: Я когда вызываю pyinstaller, пишет что не является внешней или внутренней программой